# How do you get the name of a property using the property itself

Tags: vb.net, reflection, properties, lambda

I've run into an issue where I need to get the name of a property for logging purposes.  I'm sure there is a way to do this in VB.Net using some amalgam of reflection and lambda expressions, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

What I'm trying to do is convert this:

```
objAddress.AddressLine
```

to this:

```
"AddressLine"
```

Comment: How do you know it's the objAddress.AddressLine property that you need? If it's always the same property, you could just add a constant in the class ex: ADDRESSLINE_PROPERTYNAME = "AddressLine"

Comment: This is true.  I was hoping to ensure that this logging always stays dynamic without other programmers in my team needing to know to change the logging function if they happen to change the property for any reason (which would be a violation of the Open/Closed principle, but the other programmers in my team don't follow SOLID practices).

Comment: if you can't find a dynamic way, make sure to write comments on the property says "if you change the name, don't forget the change the constant".

Comment: That's a good suggestion lotus.  If it comes down to using the constant, that is what I'll have to do.

Comment: you might also be able to define a custom attribute which defines the LogName: `<LoggingNameAttribute("Address Line")>Property AddressLine...`  Whether this is of value or could work depends on how  the logger determines what to log...that is, code that you did not show.  I *suspect* the easiest way though (short of a constant) is for the/all classes to simply have a way to return Vocabulary based on a key.

Comment: You might want to have a look at aspect oriented programming (AOP) if you want to attach the logging code to a number of properties without having to change the properties themselves. PostSharp is a good framework for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past, I've used a method I found online for doing this with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I can't remember exactly where, but this details the same resolution:

http://paulstovell.com/blog/strong-property-names

**C#**

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(Expression<Func<object>> property)
    {
        MemberExpression exp = property.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (exp != null)
        {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(exp.Member.Name));
        }
    }


}
```

**VB**

```
Public Class Test
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private _Name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.Name)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(Of T)(propertyName As Expression(Of Func(Of T)))
        Dim exp As MemberExpression = TryCast(propertyName.Body, MemberExpression)

        If exp IsNot Nothing Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(exp.Member.Name))
        End If
    End Sub



End Class
```

The main benefit of doing this is refactoring. If I ever rename my property, the Lambda (and by extension NotifyPropertyChanged event) changes automatically.

---

**Update (2015)**

It may be worth mentioning that the new features in Visual Studio 2015 make this even easier. Below is the same code shown above, but using the new `nameof` feature (Details of this, and of other new features can be found [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx)).

**C#**

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

**VB**

```
Public Class Test
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private _Name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(Name))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can even use `nameof` on the subscriber side, in order to determine if the property is the one you care about:

```
    private static void PropChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Test.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Property I care about changed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For someone who is still looking for an elegant solution, in the latest version of VB and C# you can use "nameof()".

**C#:**

```
var propertyName = nameof(objAddress.AddressLine)
```

**VB .NET:**

```
Dim propertyName = nameof(objAddress.AddressLine)
```

*Note that if you do not have an instance of an object you can just use it's class name.*

Answer (score 2):

This will show the current Method. You may want to replace the "get_" prefix of the property name.

```
Public Class People
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Address As String
        Get
            Return System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().ToString()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

' print it
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(People.Address)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Class MyClass1
    Private myProperty1 As Integer 
    ' Declare MyProperty. 

    Public Property MyProperty() As Integer 
        Get 
            Return myProperty1
        End Get 
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            myProperty1 = Value
        End Set 
    End Property 
End Class 'MyClass1

Public Class MyTypeClass
    Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Try 
            ' Get Type Object corresponding to MyClass. 
            Dim myType As Type = GetType(MyClass1)
            ' Get PropertyInfo object by passing property name. 
            Dim myPropInfo As PropertyInfo = myType.GetProperty("MyProperty")
            ' Display Name propety to console.
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} property exists in MyClass.", myPropInfo.Name)
        Catch e As NullReferenceException
            Console.WriteLine("The property does not exist in MyClass.", e.Message.ToString())
        End Try 
    End Sub 'Main
End Class 'MyTypeClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the_lotus's response to my initial question which was to use a constant.  If I find a more dynamic way to do this in the near future I'll try to post it.  lotus, if you happen to see this an answer the question with your comment, i'll switch the answered status over to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.Runtime.CompilerServices works wonders in this case, as of Net4.5. [See [Caller Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)] The optional CallerMemberName string can be used to identify what method/property called the log.

From **MSDN**

```
Private Sub DoProcessing()  
    TraceMessage("Something happened.")  
End Sub  

Public Sub TraceMessage(message As String,  
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName> Optional memberName As String = Nothing,  
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath> Optional sourcefilePath As String = Nothing,  
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber()> Optional sourceLineNumber As Integer = 0)  

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " & message)  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " & memberName)  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " & sourcefilePath)  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " & sourceLineNumber)  
End Sub  

' Sample output:  
'   message: Something happened.  
'   member name: DoProcessing  
'   source file path: C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoVB\CallerInfoVB\Form1.vb  
'   source line number: 15
```

---

Different implementation showing results from a **Property Call**

```
Class Foo
    Public ReadOnly Property ThisPropertyObject As Object
        Get
            LogManager.Ping
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
    Sub New()
      Dim this = ThisPropertyObject 
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module LogManager
        Public Sub Ping(<CallerMemberName> Optional memberName As String = Nothing,
                        <CallerFilePath> Optional sourcefilePath As String = Nothing,
                        <CallerLineNumber> Optional sourceLineNumber As Integer = 0)
            Trace.Writeline(String.Format("[{0}]|{1}|LN:{2}] <PING>",
                                          Path.GetFileName(sourcefilePath),
                                          memberName,
                                          sourceLineNumber)
                                          )
                            )
        End Sub

End Module

'! Results from 'DebugView'
' [20692][LogTestFile.vb|ThisPropertyObject|LN:62] <PING>
```